# Connect to external database from Salesforce

Tags: apex, force.com

I want to call/execute a stored procedure, which sits on an external database server, from salesforce. This SP basically takes the SF data as parameter and process it.

Is there a way to connect to other databases directly from salesforce, or creating a webservice and consuming it, is the only way.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Webservices and REST Api are the only way. You can have a look at https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000109985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot directly connect to an outside database from Salesforce. You will need some kind of middle man (integration middle-layer), whether it is a custom built webservice that you call or a market solution like Cast Iron, Dell Boomi etc.